# PHP- MySQLI prepare statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm very new to coding and I want to use MySQLi prepare statements for this piece of code, however I've spent hours trying and all i get is a whitescreen.

```
$queryLogin = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM tblUser WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' ";
$resultLogin = $mysqli->query($queryLogin);
$rowLogin = $resultLogin->fetch_assoc();
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `tblUser` WHERE `username`=? and `password`=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$result->num_rows;
$rowLogin = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rizier123 ive written it on the post

Comment: That all looks fine... Are you sure `$username` and `$password` are the data you are expecting? Turn on `display_errors` as well and see what the error is,

Comment: check if `$result->num_rows` is bigger than 0, and if not.. check if the username with that password exists in tblUser

Comment: how do i turn on display_errors, i cant get access to the php.ini file as its on my university network i think

Comment: `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to fix it with this.

```html
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser WHERE username  = ?
                  AND password  = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($rowLogin);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

after

```
$stmt->execute();
```

add

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

then you should find it right